# Server and client between PC and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, web-server, server, communication

Hi I am doing a project that I want to make Raspberry pi and Pc communicate and then Pc can get pulse signal sent from raspberry pi. The first step I think to do is to write a python server on raspberry pi side, and a client on windows side. Is it possible to get signal in this way?

and this is the code that I get from internet

The server :

---

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
  c, addr = s.accept()
  print ('Got connection from',addr)
  c.send('Thank you for connecting')
  c.close()
```

---

and the client :

---

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print (host)
port = 12345

s.connect((host, port))
print (s.recv(1024))
s.close
```

---

**But there is an error :**

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\SimpleClient.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. Please help me  :roll: Any answer are greatly accepted! Big thanks !!

Comment: oh my !! I didnt realize my code above became like this. It's hard to read! I am sorry!

Comment: will update a new one for reading easier! I am sorry!

Comment: As a general note, [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) gives some suggestions for the formatting of Python code.

Answer (score 4):

For the server, it makes sense to obtain the hostname via

```
host = socket.gethostname()
```

But how should the client know to whom to connect if you use the same command there?

In the client

```
host = socket.gethostname()
print (host)
```

prints the name of the **client**, not the host, isn't it?

Here, you might want to give the **hostname of the server** explicitly.

---

When setting up the sockets, you also might want to state the socket family and the type.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You wrote:

> There're nothing wrong with the server.

Are you going to bet on that? Paypal accepted :D

Now seriously, simply binding the socket on the server to the hostname obtained by

```
socket.gethostbyname()
```

does **NOT** work in my local network either and casts an error (111 Connection refused).

There are several options on the server side, apart from using its ip:

1. leave the hostname empty when binding
2. use the fully qualified domain name, such as **whatever.fritz.box**

On the client side, you can use the simple hostname of the server.

I tried these options when connecting from a Linux box to a Raspberry and it works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way I solved this...

Client.py

```
import socket               

s = socket.socket()        
host = ''# ip of raspberry pi 
port = 12345               
s.connect((host, port))
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

Server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = '' #ip of raspberry pi
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
  c, addr = s.accept()
  print ('Got connection from',addr)
  c.send('Thank you for connecting')
  c.close()
```