# IEEE80211n message transmission between 2 Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless, 1-wire

I have got a wifi dongle that supports the ieee80211n protocol. This one is plugged into the pi that gets real time data from the device.The data it receives from the client needs to be sent (may be broadcast) using the IEEE80211n. Now I would like to know how do I receive this data on the other raspberry pi. I have another wifi dongle with the same specification for this raspberry pi.I thought a lot about it. What ever knowledge I got about the working of IEEE80211, i could come up with the following questions. Though I am not 100% sure if I am in the right direction.

1. Can I create a ad hoc network between the 2 Pis and receive this data?
2. Will the Pi work in infrastructure mode and one of them should act as an access point? If so then which one?
3. Is there a library in any language that can be used to receive packets sent via IEEE80211n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. This might get a bit long and wordy, so stick with me.

First and foremost, networking for most computers happens in layers. This distinguishes how two computers are connected to each other (from the physical connection all the way to the application layer) such that they can actually communicate.

*(I cleaved a lot of wordy stuff out of this, I'm now thinking it's better to just get to the point)*

1. Yes, you can create an [adhoc network](http://lcdev.dk/2012/11/18/raspberry-pi-tutorial-connect-to-wifi-or-create-an-encrypted-dhcp-enabled-ad-hoc-network-as-fallback/) between two 802.11n-enabled computers. Depending on the distance that separates the two (including obstacles), it may not be the best way to send your data.
2. Yes, you can have one of the Pi's be an access point and have the other connect to it. There is an [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview) that references several different sources of how to create a Raspberry Pi access point. Note that not all WiFi adapters can act as access points. As for which one acts as the access point and which acts as the client, I don't suppose it matters. Flip a coin, ask a friend to choose, stare at tea leaves in a teapot, whatever does it for you.
3. The trick here is that once you have the two Pi's connected to a network, then the real fun *begins*. You have several ways to accomplish what you might need done, but since "one is plugged into the pi that gets real time data from the device", I will assume you mean that one of the Pi's will **always** be sending, while the other is **always** receiving.

   So for setting up this communication, I'll point you to this [Raspberry Pi StackExchange answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34056/13712) that might help you get started.