# TCP Communication Raspberry Pi and PC via Ethernet

Tags: python, ethernet, communication

I would like to reach my Raspberry Pi 2 from my PC or from PC to Raspberry Pi 2 via Ethernet cable. I aim to send/receive simple data(like "Hello world") in that way. I`ve tried some python code below. When I determine PC as server, I get *" **OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context** "* error message and when I determine Raspberry Pi as server I receive *" **error: [Errno 99] Connot assign requested address** "* error message.

Obliviously I don`t receive any error when I determine local IP 127.0.0.1 but code is broken on " **conn, addr = s.accept()** " line.

If I mention to Client side of this code, I do not get any error message for both but I realized that code is broken on **"s.send(MESSAGE)"** line.

I also tried this code on the link [Server and client between PC and Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13425/server-and-client-between-pc-and-raspberry-pi) then same issue occur, I get same errors. I`ve been working to solve this for a long time. I hope some one can help me. Thank you so much for your help.

Client:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.137.226' # this IP of my pc. When I want raspberry pi 2`s as a client, I replace it with its IP '169.254.54.195'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print ("received data:", data)
```

Server:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.137.226' # this IP of my pc. When I want raspberry pi 2`s as a server, I replace it with its IP '169.254.54.195'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20 # Normally 1024, but I want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connection address:', addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print ("received data:", data)
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, it is working perfectly. The problem lies in your setup

1st issue: **"OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context"** and **"error: [Errno 99] Connot assign requested address"** means that you have mixed up the addresses.
Fix: Try swapping the ip addresses (changes have to be done on both client and server code)

2nd issue: There might be a firewall blocking the communications
If running RPi as server: Use `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5005 -j ACCEPT` 
If running PC as server: Configure windows firewall to allow incoming TCP 5005 connections

Comment: Thank you for your help. I realized I get `s.send(MESSAGE)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str` error when I run client side. And I solved it with modify code line in client side like this `s.send((MESSAGE).encode())` Now when I test code in local IP (127.0.0.1). It works pretty good.

Comment: what do you mean by swap the IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you write your client-server code correctly then in the Raspberry put the IP address of your PC or Linux machine (obtain it with `ipconfig` or `ifconfig`) and leave the `severHost` at host = 'nothing here'.

Then, the firewall needs to be authorized to allow it to be used. Use `sudo install ufw` if you're on Linux then use the PORT 5901, or to allow other ports for communication.

Look at this website: [How To Set Up a Firewall with UFW on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04)