# When socket programming on raspberry pi, getting ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: pi-3, ethernet-port, communication, sockets

I am working on a simple project where I need two raspberry pi's communicating each other with an ethernet cable. I connect one end of ethernet cable to let's say first pi and the other end to second pi. I am trying to communicate between these two using socket programming.

I started with getting the ip address of the ethernet port at each end using `ifconfig`. 
After getting the addresses, I used `ping` to ping to the ip address from each end and could receive data packets. 
I started writing socket program for server and client. 
I followed the code given in the SO link, [TCP Communication Raspberry Pi and PC via Ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/70476/89937) and modified the ip address to my respective pi board's ip address.

server.py

```
    import socket

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = `192.168.0.1`
    port = 5000
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(1)

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print("Got connection from ", addr)
        c.send('thank you for connecting')
        c.close()
```

client.py

```
    import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = '192.168.0.10'
    port = 5000
    s.connect((host, port))
    print(s.recv(1024))
    s.close()
```

When I start the server side, everything works fine. Server is created and is listening for communication.

When I start the client side, I get `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno111] connection refused`. It happens when the program hits the line `s.connect((host, port))

After some research I came across `telnet`, though which I tried to establish a connection with the server from client side and to my surprise it was working.

I am stuck at this point and need some help in rectifying this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't ask us to guess the code.  We need to see it to comment.

Comment: Hi @joan, Thanks for replying. I have added the code snippet.

Comment: "Connection refused" == There's a system with that IP address but nothing listening on the port.  Probably it is the wrong address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your host code is

```
host = `192.168.0.1`
```

while the client code is

```
host = '192.168.0.10'
```

As you say connecting with `telnet` works, the address of the host must be 192.168.0.1, so the client should connect to 192.168.0.1 and not to 192.168.0.10.